# Does it make a difference if both parents hold a destiny knot?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

If I have a 4IV Sylveon spread out in 31spA/31spD/31spe/31atk and a 3IV Eevee spread out in 31def/31hp/31spe does it make a difference if I use two Destiny Knots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both pokémon holding a destiny knot when breeding will have the same effect as when only one of them holds a destiny knot.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will have the same effect as using just one.

When breeding you usally want to pass down a Nature to the offspring, and you achieve that giving an *Everstone* to a parent. If you use two *Destiny Knots* you can't do that.

Answer (score -2):

I have discovered that giving BOTH parents a Destiny Knot will make them spawn tons of offspring with random natures and zero offspring with just plain stats with a neutral nature.  So once you have two 5 perfect-IV parents and you just want to spawn a bunch of perfect 5-IV offspring with random natures until you get the nature you want this is the way to do it.  Then, once you get that 5 perfect-IV child with the correct nature you can give it an Everstone and leave the other intended parent of the opposite gender with the Destiny Knot.  This is a quicker and more consistent way of getting 5 perfect-IV Pokemon with your intended natures.

Comment: But you can get exactly the same effect with one Destiny Knot. The second one doesn't add anything.